# Firefox 16.02 won't play Youtube HTML5 video - I did a clean install of Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, youtube, flash-player, html5

I get the error message on the youtube video screen: "Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available.  Click here to view our FAQ about HTML5 video.

The FAQ page says what I need to supportit and then has green or red marks indicating what they detect I have.  It says I need "Video tag" and one of h.264 or WebM.  There is a green check next to "Video tag" and WebM" - so it should work.  There is a red exclamation point by h.264.

I have the Adobe Flash plugin vs. 11.2.202.228 (current) and VLC Multimedia plugin 1.1 11.0 (current).

I also tried installing the Adobe Flash player 11.6.602.171.  It says it installed okay, and it's for my browser.  The video still doesn't play.

Windows XP SP3.  I tried disabling my firewall.

This is a two month old version of Firefox, but HTML5 is MUCH older.  Firefox 10 supported it.  I can't use a newer version of Firefox because my plugins aren't updated for it yet.  But I doubt that's the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Under Firefox: Complements->Plugins->Shockwave Flash, you need deactivate or uncheck the option "Activate Protect Mode Adobe Flash". Then restart Firefox. You can play YouTube videos again.